# using leaflet with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to plot a map in shiny using leaflet, but I keep getting an error that I don't understand. Below is a minimum reproducible example. Thanks in advance for your help

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
ui = fluidPage("test", id="nav",
               leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="100%")
               )


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    print("Rendering leaflet map")
    leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.OceanBasemap") %>% 
    fitBounds(160, -30, 185, -50)
    print("Finishing rendering leaflet map")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server);
```

I get this printed to the console:

```
[1] "Rendering leaflet map"
[1] "Finishing rendering leaflet map"
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$map
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
```

The leaflet function seems to work when outside of the shiny framework hence why I am a little confused.

```
    leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.OceanBasemap") %>% 
    fitBounds(160, -30, 185, -50)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points

- The last statement in the `renderLeaflet()` call is what is returned. So, if you have a `print` statement, that is what is returned, not the leaflet object
- <s>I think you also need `shinyUI()` and `shinyServer()` wrapped around your UI and Server functions</s> - Deprecated as of shiny v0.10
- `height` is a tricky argument to get right - see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/CrzDs3eOY3M)

---

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
        leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width="100%")
        )



server <- function(session, input, output) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.OceanBasemap") %>% 
            fitBounds(160, -30, 185, -50)
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server);
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. As you can tell I am new to this shiny and leaflet business and finding debugging quite frustrating at times. Cheers.

Comment: @Cyrillm_44 I know how you feel, I still have `print` statements all over the place in my shiny apps.

Comment: ShinyUI and shinyServer are no longer required as of Shiny 0.10